# ExpressJS Router is not handling root routes

Tags: node.js, express

**UPDATE 2**: I just noticed that if on the app file I change the line:

```
app.use('/', home);
```

to:

```
app.use('/anything', home);
```

then all of the sub routes "roots" work fine.

**UPDATE 3: I just realized something else. A method on the home.js file that I did not originally include below since I didn't think was relevant turns out to be the cause of the problem.**

```
router.get('/:adventureId', (req, res) => {
   var data;
   //Irrelevant content that sets data as a JSON object.
   res.json(data);
});
```

Turns out that every single sub route "root" is passing through here and since on the other routes adventureId is undefined then data is just an empty JSON object.

**So the real question is: If this router bound to "/" and the other "roots" are bound to "/adventure" and "/test" why are all of them going through "/:adventrueId"?**

---

I have a very simple ExpressJS application on which all of the "roots" in each and every single route other than home are not being handled and they always display an empty JSON object on the page.

In some posts it was mentioned that it could be a caching issue since these routes always return a 304 status, but I've tried doing an "Empty cach and hard reload" on Chrome and even with the 200 status I still get a blank page with an empty JSON object displayed on it. I tried it with MS Edge and got the exact same behavior.

Here's what I have:

On my app file

```
var app = express();

var home = require('./routes/home');
var adventure = require('./routes/adventure');
var test = require('./routes/test');

app.use('/', home);
app.use('/adventure', adventure);
app.use('/test', test);
```

On home.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log("This works fine with http://localhost:3000.");
   res.render('home');
});

router.get('/:adventureId', (req, res) => {
   var data;
   //Irrelevant content that sets data as a JSON object.
   res.json(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

On the adventure.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/:id', (req, res) => {
   console.log("This works fine with http://localhost:3000/adventure/5.");   
   next();
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   console.log("This works fine with http://localhost:3000/adventure/5."); 
   res.render('adventure');
});

//I've also tried putting this before the other routes and the result is the same.
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log("This is never written in the console with http://localhost:3000/adventure.");
   res.send("This is never rendered in the page.");
});
```

On the test.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("This is never written on the console with http://localhost:3000/test.");
    res.send("Hello from the test root route");
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the ExpressJS Router documentation and every single blog and example I've found it says that this is how it should work so I am really at a loss here.

Thank you.

Comment: nodejs / express version ?

Comment: Why it is `.` at the every root end?

Comment: @Jérôme - Node version: 7.0.0 and Express version: 4.14.1

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN - It is just the end of the sentence inside the console.log. When I enter it on the browser there is not dot there.

Comment: Are you receiving `res.render('adventure')` when doing a GET request to the root of `adventure` route? If so, try moving the `router.get('/')` part to the top of your router file, as `/:id` can be defined or not, the router will handle it for `/` with the `:id` parameter being null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this router bound to "/" and the other "roots" are bound to "/adventure" and "/test" why are all of them going through "/:adventrueId"?

Because Express doesn't match routes based on which one matches *best*, it matches on which one matches *first*.

In your case, the route `/:advertureId` was declared before the routes for `/adventure` or `/test`. And `/adventure` and `/test` both match `/:advertureId`, so the handler for that route is called.

If you want to prevent this, declare more specific routes first:

```
app.use('/adventure', adventure);
app.use('/test', test);
app.use('/', home);
```

Comment: Indeed, as all this declarations are taken as middlewares, they are in a chain that passes one by one until the response is sent or a termination point is declared

Comment: @robertklep - You posted your answer just as I was typing mine after realizing that so you get it since First Come First Served :)

Answer (score 0):

After much going around, several updates on the question and banging my head against the keyboard I finally understood what the problem is:

By having the routers set up like this:

```
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/adventure', adventure);
app.use('/game', gameService);
app.use('/test', test);
```

and on the "home" router having this method signature:

```
router.get('/:adventureId', (req, res) => {
   var data;
   //Irrelevant content that sets data as a JSON object.
   res.json(data);
});
```

Every single sub route "root" was being interpreted as the parameter of the previous method so:

> /adventure
>   /test
>   /anything

would be handled as:

> adventrueId = adventrue
>   adventureId = test
>   adventrueId = anything

The solution was to do this:

```
app.use('/adventure', adventure);
app.use('/game', gameService);
app.use('/test', test);
app.use('/', home);
```

And now everything works.